Python and SonardCloud - using .items() on a dict instead of .keys()
I have a for loop in python that uses the keys of a dict.
for key in my_dict.keys():

Sonarcloud is giving me two medium warnings:

Consider iterating the dictionary directly instead of calling .keys()
Consider iterating with .items()

My questions,
A. Are these telling me the same thing? I don't know how to loop over a dict without .keys() or .items() (edit: I guess just iterating over the dict will return the key, thanks @Daweo)
B. Why is this better?
I don't know why the method Sonardloud is recommending is better.

Using .items() to iterate is very easy to do. I can't tell you specifically why Sonardloud dislikes you using .keys(), but this is how you can use .items()
for key, value in my_dict.items():
  print(key)



I don't know how to loop over a dict without .keys() or .items()

Just provide name of variable, that is
my_dict = {"x": 1, "y": 2, "z": 3}
for key in my_dict:
    print(key)

gives output
x
y
z


Why is this better?

better is subjective, without .keys() it is more concise, but with it is clear that you want to iterate over keys.

Sonardloud is recommending is better.

I have not used this tool, but tested version with .keys() in flake8 (which aims to reveal transgression w.r.t to PEP 8) and it did not complain, then I run black autoformatter at it (with default settings) and it did not applied any changes.

You can use .items() as well as .keys() to iterate over the dictionaries, depending on your use case.
If you only need keys from the dictionary you can use .keys()
for key in my_dict.keys():
  print(key)

Or simply
for key in my_dict:
      print(key)

Both will iterate over keys in dictionary.
But if you need both values and keys you can use .items()
for key, value in my_dict.items():
      print(key, value)

There's another way if you only require values in the dictionary.
for value in my_dict.values():
      print(value)

There's no right solution to which one is better. It depends on your use case.
